# Missing Android-support-v7-appcompat in my Android project in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to import an Android project in Eclipse., but after importing the project, I am getting errors which say "Missing android-support-v7-appcompat", "Missing Facebook SDK","Missing Google Play services lib" and "Missing library".

I can understand that I am missing libraries but do not have any clue how to add those libraries, as I am new in Android development environment.

Here, is a screenshot of the error http://screencast.com/t/iWXLkK8glkF

Comment: If you are new to Android Development, then you might want to know that Eclipse has been deprecated as a development environment for Android

Comment: I have also tried with Android studio and facing the below issue in build.gradle. I got the error mentioned in the screen shot http://screencast.com/t/nLZgVWkNz8nf

Comment: Do you have all these projects that it is trying to compile? For example, for the appcompat-v7, you only need a line in the Gradle file that says `compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1"`

Answer (score 0):

Delete the extra `apply` in the first line of your gradle file...

[image]

---

UPDATE:

You know how you have **two** gradle files? One for your application (The one you are working on right now) and the other one which is a top level build.gradle file? Put the below code in the top level build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: No luck!. i have deleted and save it. Then, i click on "Try again' but again, i found the same. Have a look on this screen shot. http://screencast.com/t/tgiNfh4VlLm... Thanks!

Comment: Updated my answer, please see above

Comment: Thanks! Joel. That error is sorted out. but as i have mentioned in my questions -- i need to add libraries. Here, issue comes with google-play-services_lib. Please check my screen shot http://screencast.com/t/9kjNI2z9r2C